# Scala vals vs vars

Tags: scala

I'm pretty new to Scala but I like to know what is the preferred way of solving this problem.  Say I have a list of items and I want to know the total amount of the items that are checks.  I could do something like so:

```
val total = items.filter(_.itemType == CHECK).map(._amount).sum
```

That would give me what I need, the sum of all checks in a immutable variable.  But it does it with what seems like 3 iterations.  Once to filter the checks, again to map the amounts and then the sum.  Another way would be to do something like:

```
var total = new BigDecimal(0)
for (
    item <- items
    if item.itemType == CHECK
) total += item.amount
```

This gives me the same result but with 1 iteration and a mutable variable which seems fine too.  But if I wanted to to extract more information, say the total number of checks, that would require more counters or mutable variables but I wouldn't have to iterate over the list again. Doesn't seem like the "functional" way of achieving what I need.

```
var numOfChecks = 0
var total = new BigDecimal(0)
items.foreach { item =>
    if (item.itemType == CHECK) {
        numOfChecks += 1
        total += item.amount
    }
}
```

So if you find yourself needing a bunch of counters or totals on a list is it preferred to keep mutable variables or not worry about it do something along the lines of:

```
val checks = items.filter(_.itemType == CHECK)
val total = checks.map(_.amount).sum
return (checks.size, total)
```

which seems easier to read and only uses `vals`

Comment: The `for` expression is actually compiled to a `map`, a `filter` and a `foreach`, so it's equivalent to your first example.

Comment: This is no longer accurate: the for comprehension uses withFilter, not filter, unless the collection has no withFilter method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `foldLeft` for that:

```
(0 /: items) ((total, item) => 
   if(item.itemType == CHECK) 
      total + item.amount 
   else 
      total
)
```

The following code will return a tuple (number of checks -> sum of amounts):

```
((0, 0) /: items) ((total, item) => 
   if(item.itemType == CHECK) 
      (total._1 + 1, total._2 + item.amount) 
   else 
      total
)
```

Comment: forgot about folding / this would give me all my data back in one nice tuple

Answer (score 8):

Another way of solving your problem in one iteration would be to use views or iterators:

```
items.iterator.filter(_.itemType == CHECK).map(._amount).sum
```

or

```
items.view.filter(_.itemType == CHECK).map(._amount).sum
```

This way the evaluation of the expression is delayed until the call of `sum`.

If your items are case classes you could also write it like this:

```
items.iterator collect { case Item(amount, CHECK) => amount } sum
```

Answer (score 7):

I find that speaking of doing "three iterations" is a bit misleading -- after all, each iteration does less work than a single iteration with everything. So it doesn't automatically follows that iterating three times will take longer than iterating once.

Creating temporary objects, now *that* is a concern, because you'll be hitting memory (even if cached), which isn't the case of the single iteration. In those cases, `view` will help, even though it adds more method calls to do the same work. Hopefully, JVM will optimize that away. See [Moritz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401835/moritz)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269489/scala-vals-vs-vars/4269640#4269640) for more information on views.